# CoordinatorLayout adds space between AppBarLayout and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

`CoordinatorLayout` adds space between `AppBarLayout` and `RecyclerView`. Not sure whether its the `Toolbar` or `AppBarLayout`.

Screenshot of the rendered layout on phone:

[image: Screenshot of the rendered layout on phone]

The design rendering on Studio doesn't how this space.

Any idea on what's going on?

The Code Itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_home_framelayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  >

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/activity_home_coordinator"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      tools:context=".ActivitySignIn">


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:theme="@style/OTGToolbarTheme"
          >

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="You are logged in"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_home_articlecontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/NavigationDrawer"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/tlgray0"
      android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <ProgressBar
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:indeterminate="true"/>
  </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove below line from your first Recycler View which id  is **activity_home_articlecontainer**

```
 android:layout_gravity="start"
```